# Unable to fetch accountId of User in Test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, callout, apexrest

I am stuck in scenario while writing logic for my Test class.
I am not able to access `Contact.AccountId` of `User` created in test case.

I have created a `TestUtility` class for creating the community user. The code is given below for reference:

```
public with sharing class TestUtility {

    public static User createUser(String roleId, String profId, String firstName, String lastName){
        User tempUser = prepareUser(roleId, profId, firstName, lastName);
        return tempUser;
    }

    private static User prepareUser(String roleId, String profId, String firstName, String lastName) {  

        String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();  
        String dateString =   
        String.valueof(Datetime.now()).replace(' ','').replace(':','').replace('-','');  
        Integer randomInt = Integer.valueOf(math.rint(math.random()*1000000));  
        String uniqueName = orgId + dateString + randomInt;  
        User tempUser = new User(  
            FirstName = firstName,  
            LastName = lastName,  
            email = uniqueName + '@sfdc' + orgId + '.org',  
            Username = uniqueName + '@sfdc' + orgId + '.org',  
            EmailEncodingKey = 'ISO-8859-1',  
            Alias = uniqueName.substring(18, 23),  
            TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',  
            LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',  
            LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US', 
            IsActive = true, 
            ProfileId = profId
        );    
        if( String.isBlank(roleId) == false ){
            tempUser.UserRoleId = roleId;
        }
        return tempUser;  
    }

    public static User createCommunityUser(String contactId, String profId, String firstName, String lastName) {
        User tempUser = prepareUser('', profId, firstName, lastName);
        tempUser.ContactId = contactId;
        return tempUser;
    }

    public static Account createAccount(String Name){
        Account portalAccount = new Account(name = Name );
        return portalAccount;
    }
    public static Contact createContact(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String accountId){
        Contact portalContact = new contact(
            FirstName = firstName, 
            LastName = lastName, 
            Email = email, 
            AccountId = accountId
        );
        return portalContact;
    }
}
```

TestUtility is used for creating account, contact and the community user.

I have made use of this Utility class in my Test class named `UserHandlerTest`. The code for it looks like below:

```
@isTest
public class UserHandlerTest {

    @isTest
    public static void createUser(){
        Id profileId = [Select Id From Profile Where Name ='System Administrator'].Id;
        User u = TestUtility.createUser('',profileId,'Fname','Test');
        System.runAs( u ){
            Account acc = TestUtility.createAccount('Test Account');
            insert acc;
        }
    }
    @isTest
    public static void createCommunityUser(){
        Id profileId = [Select Id From Profile Where Name ='CT'].Id;
        Account acc = TestUtility.createAccount('Test Account');
        insert acc;
        Contact con = TestUtility.createContact('test','Contact','test@gmail.com',acc.Id);
        insert con;      
        User u = TestUtility.createCommunityUser(con.Id,profileId,'Fname','Test');
        system.debug('User Account::: '+u.Contact.AccountId); ***//getting this as null***
        
        Test.startTest();
        UserHandler.deactivateUsers(new List<Id>{acc.Id});
        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

The main class named `UserHandler` is used to make the user inactive by normal logic as given below:

```
public class UserHandler {

@future
    public static void deactivateUsers(List<Id> accountIds) {
    
    
    if (accountIds != null && !accountIds.isEmpty()){
        Map<Id, User> usrMap = new Map<Id, User>([SELECT Id, IsActive, Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Contact.AccountId IN :accountIds LIMIT 1]); ***//This query returns null in test class debug logs***
                List<User> usersToUpdate = new List<User>();
                for (Id accountId : accountIds) {

                    for (User communityUser : usrMap.values()) {
                        if (communityUser.Contact.AccountId == accountId) {
                            communityUser.IsActive = false;
                            usersToUpdate.add(communityUser);
                            break; // Exit the inner loop
                        }
                    }
                    
                }

                if (!usersToUpdate.isEmpty()) {
                    update usersToUpdate;
                }
         }
    }
}
```

I am not able to understand why the value of AccountId is seen missing for the user even if I am passing it via utility class.

Comment: Hi there, I can see two main problems in the code. 

1. You are creating a user in code, but not actually in the instance. 'Insert user' is never used to create a new user in the salesforce org. 
2. The user object does not have Contact lookup. So Contact.AccountId cannot be used in this regard. AFAIK, you cannot create a custom lookup either.

You need to user user Ids instead of account Ids in the query. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response @AsadullahShaikh Do you recommend using Test.isRunningTest() for getting the user directly and executte existing logic for !Test.isRunningTest()?

Comment: @AsadullahShaikh Is there any better way to write this class, thanks.

Comment: Hi there, I'll share the updated code in the comment today.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
User u = TestUtility.createCommunityUser(con.Id,profileId,'Fname','Test');
```

that calls

```
public static User createCommunityUser(String contactId, String profId, String firstName, String lastName) {
    User tempUser = prepareUser('', profId, firstName, lastName);
    tempUser.ContactId = contactId;
    return tempUser;
}
```

The return value from `CreateCommunityUser` is a `User` record that will have the value `User.ContactId` populated because you created the `User` object with that value.

But, I don't see the test method actually inserting the User

```
User u = TestUtility.createCommunityUser(con.Id,profileId,'Fname','Test');
insert u;  // missing! see Asadullah's comment #1 that was spot on
```

But when an object is created via DML, the lookup objects aren't in memory.  You'll need to requery the User to get the value of AccountId to use in the debug statement

```
u = [SELECT Id, Contact.AccountId, Contact.Account.Name FROM User WHERE Id = :u.Id];
```

**Side note**

I'd avoid Test.isRunningTest in PROD code as a matter of principle. PROD code is PROD code. Far better solutions involve using interfaces that are mocked in test methods should the need arise

Comment: Thanks for your response @cropredy 
I tried the above logic by adding another SOQL as below
```User u = TestUtility.createCommunityUser(con.Id,profileId,'Fname','Test');```
```u = [SELECT Id, Contact.AccountId, isActive FROM User WHERE LastName='Test' LIMIT 1];```

However when I try to fetch ```Contact.AccountId```, It is still null.

The Map of ```usrMap``` is still null

Comment: updated answer; I missed the obvious